# Set the priority of attributes when creating XML nodes in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

With the following code i create xml nodes:

```
set @imageListXml = (
    select 
        'IMG' + CAST( m.entry_id AS VARCHAR) as '@id',
        (select title from titles where entry_id=m.tid) as 'textelements/title',
        'TEST' as 'references/reference/@body',
        'IMG' + CAST( m.entry_id AS VARCHAR) as 'references/reference/@value'

     from media m   

        )
    FOR XML PATH('image'), root('imagelist')
    )
```

which creates something like that:

```
<imagelist>
  <image id="IMG1111">
    <textelements>
       <title>Test 1111</title>
    </textelements>
    <references>
      <reference body="TEST" value="IMG1111" />
    </references>
  </image>
</imagelist>
```

how can i put value attribute first or vice versa? I think it depends on what i state first in select statement. Am i correct?

Comment: Attribute order within an element is irrelevant for XML, according to the XML standard.

Answer (score 0):

```
set @imageListXml = (
  select 'IMG' + CAST( m.entry_id AS VARCHAR) as '@id',
    (select title from titles where entry_id=m.tid) as 'textelements/title',
    'IMG' + CAST( m.entry_id AS VARCHAR) as 'references/reference/@value',
    'TEST' as 'references/reference/@body' 
  from media m
  FOR XML PATH('image'), root('imagelist')
)
```

will return the `value` attribute before the `body` attribute. However, I do not think that this is specified anywhere, because attributes within a XML element is unordered. They are always referred by name, never by index.

That said, some orderings are more human-readable / prettier than others, so if a human will cast eyes upon the generated XML, it makes sense to ensure a better attribute ordering.